# Reshaping a list of list in python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

I have a list of list of size 3 that is:

```
positions_train = [[0.300,0.4500,0.5900,0.7812],[0.1200,0.3400,0.6700,0.8400],[0.210,0.2900,0.500,0.6700]]
```

I want to reshape it such that it becomes (3,4) of type float64 which I can give it to a fully connected neural network because otherwise it gives me an error.

I've tried reshaping it but it doesn't work. I also tried:

```
 np.asarray(positions_train)
```

It converts it to size (10,) of type object.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape the array?

```
import numpy as np

positions_train = [[0.300,0.4500,0.5900,0.7812],
                   [0.1200,0.3400,0.6700,0.8400],
                   [0.210,0.2900,0.500,0.6700]]

k = np.asarray(positions_train).reshape((3,4))

print(k)
print(k.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[[0.3    0.45   0.59   0.7812]
 [0.12   0.34   0.67   0.84  ]
 [0.21   0.29   0.5    0.67  ]] 
float64
```

Comment: I tried that as well before posting the question but I got another error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,4)

Comment: @sha then check your data - with the example you gave it works - simple as that. The data you use probably has less elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right. One of my list was not of specified length. Thank you Patrick.